# Express as a full-range Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

> > Express 
> >     $$f(t) = \begin{cases}
> > 0,& 0\leqslant t<\pi\\
> > -\sin t,& \pi\leqslant t\leqslant 2\pi.
> > \end{cases}
> > $$
> >     as a full-range Fourier series.

I found $ C_0 $ to be $2/\pi$. But I'm having trouble expressing $C_n$. 
I've messed around with it for a long time but I can't figure out where to go. Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We compute the $\cos$ coefficients:
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac 2{2\pi} \int_\pi^{2\pi}-\sin t\cos\left(2\pi t\frac n{2\pi} \right)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac1\pi \int_\pi^{2\pi} \sin t\cos nt\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac1\pi \left[\frac{n \sin (t) \sin (n t)+\cos (t) \cos (n t)}{n^2-1}\right]_\pi^{2\pi}\\
&= \frac{\cos (2 \pi  n)}{n^2-1} + \frac{\cos (\pi  n)}{n^2-1}, n\geqslant 2
\end{align}
Since $\cos(2\pi n)=1$ and $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$ for integers $n$, this reduces to
$$
\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{(1-n^2)\pi}.
$$
Similarly, we compute the $\sin$ coefficients:
$$
b_1 = -\frac1\pi\int_\pi^{2\pi}\sin^2t\ \mathsf dt = -\frac12,
$$

\begin{align}
b_n &= \frac 2{2\pi} \int_\pi^{2\pi}-\sin t\sin\left(2\pi t\frac n{2\pi} \right)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left[\frac{n \sin (t) \cos (n t)-\cos (t) \sin (n t)}{n^2-1}\right]_\pi^{2\pi}\\
&= -\frac1\pi\left(\frac{\sin (2 \pi  n)}{n^2-1} +\frac{\sin (\pi  n)}{n^2-1}\right), n\geqslant 2.
\end{align}
Since $\sin(2\pi n)=\sin(\pi n)=0$ for integers $n$, this reduces to zero.
It follows that the Fourier series for $f$ is
$$
\frac1\pi -\frac12\sin t +\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{(1-n^2)\pi}\cos nt.
$$

Comment: What you called "the Fourier series for f" dropped the sines and cosines...

Comment: What? The sine terms are all zero, and the cosine terms sum to the opposite of the DC component, yielding a sum of zero.

Comment: Just as a sanity check: so you'd claim that the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function that is not $0$ in $L^2$ is $0$? Wouldn't that contradict Parseval's identity, that the sum of squares of the absolute values of the coefficients is the integral of the square of the absolute value of the function... for example?

Comment: @paulgarrett I have revised my answer to $\frac i2$.

Comment: Well, so the Fourier series produces a constant value? $\sin$ is not constant. So now it doesn't necessarily contradict Parseval, but there is still a disconnect. By Fourier-Dirichlet for this particular function, its Fourier series converges pointwise to the function at every point. Oop. I really think your ending misrepresents your computation: you just added up the numerical Fourier coefficients, rather than using them as coefficients of cosines or sines...

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks for pointing out my error. Indeed, you are correct.

Comment: Your series is undefined, with division by zero at $n=1$.

Comment: With the discontinuity at $n=1$, we need to show that there is a $\sin$ term instead of a $\cos$ term (i.e. $a_1=0$ and $b_1=\frac{-1}2$).

Comment: @Jam Okay, it should be correct now.